# Java Servlet filter not entering doFilter method properly

Tags: java, servlets, filter

I have a maven project, without a web.xml file, as it has so far not been necessary. I have my filter class, that checks rather or not a user is logged in but checking if the userAttribute "user" is null in the current sessio, if it is, the user gets redirected to the login page. here is my code.

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/LogInSample /FrontController?command=createorder") 
public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
   //pre-processing (ting der sker inden filteret bliver taget i brug)
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    if (httpRequest.getRequestURI().startsWith("/LogInSample/FrontController?command=createorder")
            || httpRequest.getRequestURI().startsWith("/customerpage")) {
        HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession();
        System.out.println("inside of authentication filter");
        if (session.getAttribute("user") == null) {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/login").forward(request, response);
        }

    }

    chain.doFilter(request, response);
    System.out.println("after do filter");
    //post-processing comes after this command
```

i just copied a url in which i would like the filter to filter, just to test it out, however it does not even enter the doFilter method,

Is it my annotations that are wrong? Shoudl i create a web.xml file, and configure the annotations that way, or

Comment: I think multiple `urlPatterns` should be put within an array: `{"/LogInSample", "/FrontController?command=createorder"}`. Also not sure the url parameter will work...

Comment: What do you suggest i should instead?

Comment: and that is the entire url i put in

Comment: you can not have spaces in your URL pattern. in the first @WebFilter, I can see a space after the "/LogInSample /" . And also I am not sure you can use parameters in the url pattern.